# templatefield or button column

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagridview

I see a lot of code samples that use template fields for say a button column. However, asp has a ButtonField in gridview columns. What is the difference, if any, between quickly throwing a buttonfield column in a gridview over configuring a templatefield column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any pre-built column will be easier to use, and be automatically data bound.  A templatefield can contain anything, buttons, 10 different buttons, another gridview, etc etc.  So it can be whatever you want, but you need to deal with all the controls inside manually.  If you are just looking for a column with one button, stick to the buttonfield control.